# Basic S Column Alignment with siunitx package

Tags: tables, siunitx

OK, what am I missing here? Why is the `S` column not aligning on the decimal:

[image]

The desired result is the data aligned on the decimal and centered within the column:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{S}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Measured Values} \\
        \SI{0.003 1}{\meter} \\
        \SI{0.003 123}{\meter} \\
        \SI{0.003 45}{\meter} \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case if you have to use different units for different numbers, you have these possibilities with `table-space-text-post` and `table-align-text-post`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.6,table-space-text-post = \si{\meter}]}
    {Measured Values} \\
        0.0031\si{\meter}   \\
        0.003123\si{\meter} \\
        0.00345\si{\meter}  \\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.7,table-align-text-post = false]}  %% note 1.7 here just to align things at center
    {Measured Values} \\
        0.0031\,\si{\meter}   \\
        0.003123\,\si{\meter} \\
        0.00345\,\si{\meter}  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also `pre` version of above commands - `table-align-text-pre` which does the same before the number.

Comment: Very nice; I didn't know about these keys until reading your answer. Is it possible to add a thin space to obtain the proper spacing at the widest number? I tried `table-space-text-post = {\,\si{\meter}}` but the result did not change.

Comment: I think you should add a `\,` before the unit to get the same spacing (as the \SI{}{}) macro would produce) - especially in the second example.

Comment: Oh, I see, it works if used in each individual row. I was trying to set it in the post-space key. I think it'd be nice to set it there once rather than in every row of the table.

Comment: @PaulGessler: I agree, but it may be an extra work for Joseph :)

Comment: @PaulGessler If you want something to appear in every row, the `array` `>{...}` mechanism is the way to go. (I'd strongly prefer dividing through as you've said in your answer, otherwise there is repeated information for no reason.)

Comment: @HarishKumar BTW, you'd be better with `\,\si{\metre}` as this way the unit is in 'interpreted' mode (would make a difference if the unit was _e.g._ `\per\metre`).

Comment: @JosephWright Changed right away! Thanks for noting. :)

Answer (score 16):

The `S` column type is meant to take inputs in the same format as the single mandatory argument to `siunitx`'s `\num{}` command. Anything else is interpreted as text (for headings, etc.) and is centered about the decimal point location.

This is why you see the overall centering behavior: The `\SI{}{}` is interpreted as something that is "not a number" and is formatted as header text or other material.

To typeset the units, use an `s` column, which takes inputs in the same form as the mandatory argument to the `\si{}` command. This should only be used if the units are not the same for every row in the table.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.6]s}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Measured Values} \\
        0.0031   & \meter \\
        0.003123 & \meter \\
        0.00345  & \meter \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the units of a particular column are the same for every row (as is the case for most tables), use the recommendation of Section 9.3 of the [`siunitx` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx); that is, represent the numbers using dimensionless ratios:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.6]}
    {Measured Values/\si{\meter}} \\
        0.0031   \\
        0.003123 \\
        0.00345  \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or (my preference):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.6]}
    {Measured Values (\si{\meter})} \\
        0.0031   \\
        0.003123 \\
        0.00345  \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how `table-format=1.6` is used to specify the maximum number of integer and decimal digits in each column entry. This allows for proper centering of the data. Also, I used curly braces around the heading to "protect" it and mark it as non-numerical data. This is not required here, because `siunitx` is pretty smart about detecting these cases. The curly brace protection is useful in certain cases where `siunitx` gets confused (integer index headings, for example).

Comment: Hmmm, I just I just assumed that the `S` column type from the `siunitx` package would know about the `\SI{}{}` macro form the `\siunitx` package. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Well `\SI` wouldn't make sense in any case: it's a _quantity_ not a _number_, so what the logical outcome of 'align in a numerical column' is is undefined.

Comment: @Josef Wright: Please consider supporting `\SI` macros in `S` columns by way of aligning the `\num` part of them and adding the `\si` part as post-text. In my view quantities should get compatible alignment possibilities as bare numbers because they contain numbers.