# Column Alignment for SI Error Range

Tags: tables, pdftex, longtable, siunitx, units

I have a special problem concerning the column alignment of values which are an error range (separated by `$\pm$` or `±`). Since it usually does a great job at typesetting numbers and units, I'm using the `siunitx` package.

#### What I got:

Now I have two approaches to my problem divided here into `Table 1` and `Table 2` (see code). While `Tab. 1` gets the centering but not the spacing right, it is reversed for `Tab. 2`. `Tab. 1` is close to a solution, but I still prefer the `Tab. 2` way, since it is better readable code, is less tweaking of options and I can directly see in `SI{x.xx(xxx)}{}` which values belong together. And since the data input works automated from `R`, I don't have to write `SI{x.xx(xxx)}{}` or actually the customized `\ErrRange{x}{y}` every time.

#### What I want:

**1.** If I use the `S[table-format=x.x] @{\,\( \pm \)\,} S[table-format=x.x]` to format my columns, I get the centering right. But how do I control space between values *consistently*? It is not straight forward and needs a lot of tweaking to get right. (See `Tab. 1`)

**2.** If I use `SI{x.xx(xxx)}{}` as an entry type, how do I get it to center primary around `±` and secondary around `x.xx` as well as `xxx`? For this question, I got the impression that I have to tell `siunitx` somehow that I'm using a `S` column here even if I do!? (See `Tab. 2`)

#### What I found:

I tried to get more information on the `siunitx` package and its usage, but neither the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) nor other questions could help me ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407237/siunitx-table-column-with-and-without-units),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196099/basic-s-column-alignment-with-siunitx-package),[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336996/align-numbers-and-ranges-in-siunitx-column-type-s)). There was [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418068/how-to-adjust-the-widths-of-s-type-columns-in-a-table) which discussed the spacing for the `S` column, but this adds nothing new to my solution. They always discuss exclusively one of both points but never both together.

The closest to my question came this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200212/format-table-with-aligned-values-errors-and-units-and-parentheses), from which I tried to add some `\sisetup` options like `table-number-alignment=center` and some `S` column options like `S[separate-uncertainty,table-figures-uncertainty=1]`. They did not change a thing. When I added `table-figures-integer = 1` & `table-figures-decimal = 2` (with respective values), this even made the alignment in `Tab. 1` worse.

Please note in the picture below, how the first table has this weird space problem and how the second ignores the SI-centering:

[image]

#### My code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty, multi-part-units=single, bracket-numbers=false, range-phrase=--, range-units=single}
\newcommand{\ErrRange}[2]{\SI{#1(#2)}{}}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Table with $\pm$ as column separator }
\begin{longtable}{
        >{\itshape}p{3.5cm}
        S[table-format=2.2]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}
        S[table-format=1.1]%
        S[table-format=3.2]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}
        S[table-format=2.2]% 
        S[table-format=2.1]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}
        S[table-format=2.1]%
    }
    \caption{The entries of this table are centered nicely, but the distances are awful to get right!}%
    \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Taxon}}      & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Height (m)}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{DBH (cm)}}   &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Moss Cover (\%)}}\\
    \endfirsthead

 Acer pseudoplatanus &  14.8 & 4.1 &  35.33 & 20.19 & 11.5 & 16.8 \\ 
 Acer platanoides    &  14.4 & 4.2 & 100.33 & 15.28 & 18.0 & 20.8 \\ 
 Picea abies         &  14.8 & 3.8 &  32.44 & 13.37 &  0.3 &  0.8 \\ 
\end{longtable} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Table with SI-range multicolumns}
\begin{longtable}{
        >{\itshape}p{3.5cm}
        *{3}S}
    \caption{Here the table's code is better readable, but the centering is incorrect.}%
    \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Taxon}}  & 
    \textbf{Height (m)} &
    \textbf{DBH (cm)}   &
    \textbf{Moss Cover (\%)}\\

 Acer pseudoplatanus & \ErrRange{14.8}{41}  & \ErrRange{35.33}{2019}  & \ErrRange{11.5}{168} \\ 
 Acer platanoides    & \ErrRange{14.4}{42}  & \ErrRange{100.33}{1528} & \ErrRange{18.0}{208} \\ 
 Picea abies         & \ErrRange{14.8}{38}  & \ErrRange{32.44}{1337}  & \ErrRange{0.3}{8} \\ 
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

## EDIT:

Based on the solutions by `Zarko` and `samcarter`, my problem now is clearer to me. After `Zarko's` explanation in the comments, one additional problem could be that the smallest value of a column is smaller than the errors of some other value of that column.
However, contrary to the implication in the comments, some/most of these are realistic values.

As a short background information:
These are data on different tree species of which I estimated the height, dbh (diameter at breast height) and the moss cover. Since I did this for well over a hundred individuals per species (disregarding the size and age), the variation should be quite large. And while it is true that I overemphasized some values, the moss cover values are all my real values. So, both *Acer* species are supposed to have way more mosses (and more variation in it) than the *Picea* species. That means that I probably cannot use the answer of `Zarko` but have to take a workaround like `samcarter's`

## EDIT 2:

I guess you're right about one thing: I did not mean the standard error but the standard deviation. However, I need the same format and this should therefore not change anything.

Comment: from your eddits i can conclude, that you actualy like to present three values: minimal, maximal and average. this you can declare/present as accuracy of measurement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

using features of `siunitx` at table setting and standard SI notation for uncertainty for numbers inputs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         table-figures-uncertainty=2,
         table-number-alignment = center,
        }

\usepackage[active, floats, tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Reserving space in \texttt{S} columns.}
\label{tab:S:space}
    \sisetup{
    table-figures-integer = 3,
    table-figures-decimal = 2,
    separate-uncertainty,
    table-figures-uncertainty = 1
  }
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-figures-decimal = 1]
S
S[table-figures-decimal = 1]
}
    \toprule
\textbf{Taxon}      & {\textbf{Height (m)}}
                                & {\textbf{DBH (cm)}}
                                                & {\textbf{Moss Cover (\%)}}    \\
    \midrule
Acer pseudoplatanus &  14.8(41) &  35.33(2019)  & 11.5(168)                     \\
Acer platanoides    &  14.4(42) & 100.33(1528)  & 18.0(208)                     \\
Picea abies         &  14.8(38) &  32.44(1337)  &  0.3(08)                      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**addendum**:

in the case that you like to have anchored number at their decimal points and at tolerance sign (don't doing this, it is not in frame of SI standard) with explicit writing of `\pm` signs (what wouldn't do ever), than you have the mismatch at spaces. they in your solution arise from fact that content of two column cells are wider than natural width of spanned column. this you can solve on two ways:

- make two column cells narrower, for example set them in two lines

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, longtable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Table with $\pm$ as column separator }
\begingroup
\begin{longtable}{@{}
        >{\itshape}l
        S[table-format=2.1]@{$\,\pm\,$}S[table-format=1.1]%
        S[table-format=3.2]@{$\,\pm\,$}S[table-format=2.2]%
        S[table-format=2.1]@{$\,\pm\,$}S[table-format=2.1]%
                    @{}}
    \caption{The entries of this table are centered nicely, but the distances are awful to get right!}%
    \\
\thead{Taxon}           &
\mcc{Height\\ (m)}      &
\mcc{DBH\\ (cm)}        &
\mcc{Moss\\ Cover\\ (\%)} \\
    \endfirsthead
Acer pseudoplatanus &  14.8 & 4.1 &    35.33 & 20.19 & 11.5 & 16.8 \\
Acer platanoides    &  14.4 & 4.2 &   100.33 & 15.28 & 18.0 & 20.8 \\
Picea abies         &  14.8 & 3.8 &   32.44  & 13.37 &  0.3 &  0.8 \\r
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

- or make `S` columns wider, for example with increase number of integer and decimal digits:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}

%------------- show page layout. don't use this in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\section*{Table with $\pm$ as column separator }
\begingroup
%\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}
    >{\itshape}l
    S[table-format=4.1]@{$\,\pm\,$}S[table-format=1.4]%
    S[table-format=3.2]@{$\,\pm\,$}S[table-format=2.3]%
    S[table-format=6.1]@{$\,\pm\,$}S[table-format=2.6]%
                  @{}}
\caption{The entries of this table are centered nicely, but the distances are awful to get right!}%
    \\
\text{Taxon}            &
\mcc{Height (m)}        &
\mcc{DBH (cm)}          &
\mcc{Moss Cover (\%)}   \\
    \endfirsthead
Acer pseudoplatanus &  14.8 & 4.1 &    35.33 & 20.19 & 11.5 & 16.8 \\
Acer platanoides    &  14.4 & 4.2 &   100.33 & 15.28 & 18.0 & 20.8 \\
Picea abies         &  14.8 & 3.8 &   32.44  & 13.37 &  0.3 &  0.8 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**off-topic**:

after reading edited of question,  i thought that the next solution would probably be more correct:

[image]

mwe for this suggestion is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\newcommand\mcfour[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}

%------------- show page layout. don't use this in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\section*{new version of table}
\begingroup
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\renewcommand\cmidrulekern{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\itshape}l
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]
         S[table-format=3.1]
         S[table-format=2.1]
         S[table-format=2.2]}
                }
\caption{Results of observation,  numbers are dummy}     \\
    \toprule
    &   \mcfour{Height (m)}
    &   \mcfour{DBH (cm)}
    &   \mcfour{Moss Cover (\%)}        \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-13}
\text{Taxon}
    & {min} & {max} & {mean}& {$\mu_{1/2}$}
    & {min} & {max} & {mean}& {$\mu_{1/2}$}
    & {min} & {max} & {mean}& {$\mu_{1/2}$}  \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \bottomrule
\endfoot
Acer pseudoplatanus
    & 10.0  & 18.39 & 14.8  & 15.5
    & 10.0  & 57.00 & 35.33 & 33,15
    &  0.0  & 28.32 & 10.5  & 16.8      \\

    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

(where `$\mu_{1/2}$` means `median`).

Comment: +1, however the numbers in the last column are not aligned by their decimal markers

Comment: no. they not. `siunitx` doesn't support aligning at two markers. beside this all uncertainty in table is fragile (wrong).  tolerances had not to be bigger than last defined digit in number. or today basing measurement rules doesn't valid anymore (why you for example say length is 14.8 m with tolerance 4 m? :-(. do i'm wrong?

Comment: I totally agree that the number of significant figures does not make sense.

Comment: @bamphe, do you read addendum to my answer?

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's a hell of an answer :)
As I said, I would like the format like I have it in the question (in plant ecology it's not that much about precision of measurements since there are so many random environmental factors...)
However, your addendum still gives me the possibility to tweak it to my liking and I would say it's a bit less messier than samcarter's solution ;)
For all others with similar problems, the answer actually explains various underlying concepts. Very cool!

Comment: Oh, what's also great is that you used an extra macro to shorten the `\multicolumn` stuff. Don't know, but I never thought about that. Now, the eleven column names of my actual table are much better readable!

Answer (score 2):

Coincidently I was fighting with a similar problem today myself.

For now I use `\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{DBH (cm)}}` as a workaround. However this requires to manually add space between the columns...

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty, multi-part-units=single, bracket-numbers=false, range-phrase=--, range-units=single}
\newcommand{\ErrRange}[2]{\SI{#1(#2)}{}}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Table with $\pm$ as column separator }
\begin{longtable}{
        >{\itshape}p{3.5cm}
        S[table-format=2.1]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}S[table-format=1.1]%
        p{0.2em}S[table-format=3.2]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}S[table-format=2.2]% 
        p{1em}S[table-format=2.1]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}S[table-format=2.1]%
    }
    \caption{The entries of this table are centered nicely, but the distances are awful to get right!}%
    \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Taxon}}      & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Height (m)}}} & &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{DBH (cm)}}}   & &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Moss Cover (\%)}}}\\
    \endfirsthead

 Acer pseudoplatanus &  14.8 & 4.1 &&  35.33 & 20.19 & &11.5 & 16.8 \\ 
 Acer platanoides    &  14.4 & 4.2 && 100.33 & 15.28 & &18.0 & 20.8 \\ 
 Picea abies         &  14.8 & 3.8 &&  32.44 & 13.37 & & 0.3 &  0.8 \\ 
\end{longtable} 


\end{document}
```

[image]